# How to update Bluetooth gamepad drive to fix weird multiple buttons behavior

Tags: windows, drivers, bluetooth

So I just bought a [Mocute 050 gamepad](https://br.gearbest.com/game-controllers/pp_415071.html) and paired with my OS (Windows 10) without any issue.

However, after playing a bit I've noticed a very strange behavior:

Whenever I hold use some specific combination of buttons (eg: L Trigger + R Trigger) the controller can't handle some other buttons correctly.

Example of behavior:

1. I press L Trigger + R Trigger and maintain pressed;
2. If I press the A button, instead of only call the A button, the X button is also called;

This happens with other combinations like A + X + R1 - Also calls L1

I've attached two images, one showing the buttons I've pressed and one showing the buttons recognized by the mapping software.

[image]

[image]

Additional info:

1. I've tried multiple mapping softwares, all have same problem;
2. Other gamepads works with no problems;

**Question: Is there any way to update my bluetooth gamepad's driver to try to fix this problem?**

Comment: Is your question how to update the driver, or whether updating the driver would fix it?  You can always check on whether there's a newer driver and try it.  But do you know if this is a bug?  There are a limited number of buttons, and they are designed to handle a certain range of combinations.  It could be that they just never anticipated people using the combinations you did in the way that you did, and it's just a limitation.  (cont'd)

Comment: Before you invest time trying to "fix" it, it might be worth contacting customer support at the manufacturer to verify that it is not supposed to do that.   Or ask on gaming sites whether other people experience the same thing (if others can't replicate the issue, you might just have a defective unit).